# Meaning of "and for most" and "the time has come to do more"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> As of this moment, the United States and only four other NATO members meet this basic standard.  Now, while we commend the few nations that are on track to achieve that goal, the truth is that many others, including some of our largest allies, still lack a clear and credible path to meeting this minimum goal. Let me be clear on this point: The President of the United States expects our allies to keep their word to fulfill this commitment, **and for most that means the time has come to do more.**  [Remarks by Vice President Mike Pence](https://ee.usembassy.gov)

I would like to know what the last sentence means.

In particular, what does "and for most" and "the time has come to do more" mean?

I googled them but I could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**most** refers back to "our allies"

> The President of the United States expects our allies to keep their word to fulfill this commitment, and for most **of our allies** that means the time has come to do more.

So Mr Pence believes that the majority of allies are not currently fulfulling their commitment.  They may currently be taking some steps, but now must **do more**.

> The time has come

has the implication that in the past there may have been a reason to defer taking action, but right now they should take action, this is the proper time for action.

Comment: Thanks. Then "the time has come to do more" means it is time that the allies must do something more?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make this explicit.